# Is there a difference in usage between the idioms "through the ringer" and "through the wringer"?

Tags: differences, idioms, word-usage

Is there any difference in usage between the idioms "through the ringer" and "through the wringer"? As I have found out they are pretty similar (for example [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+through+the+ringer)  and [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/through+the+wringer)) but I have no idea when to use one instead of the other.

Comment: https://howcanisaythat.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/through-the-wringer-or-through-the-ringer/ and http://www.beedictionary.com/common-errors/ringer_vs_wringer

Comment: Use “through the ringer” when you want to portray yourself as someone who doesn’t know that it should be “through the wringer”

Comment: Yes, there is an ifference.  One has the initial letter of a word omitted and the other doesn't.

Comment: My girlfriend called. I talked to her through the ringer.

Comment: Wringer is correct. Ringer doesn't make sense unless you're Neo from the Matrix. He literally went through the ringer (phone).

Comment: Start by looking up *wringer* and *ringer* in the dictionary. That will tell you what you are saying.

Comment: I've added new links to the question, that says that there are two possible forms of usage.

Comment: Of course it should be noted that one definition of "ringer" is one person/horse/whatever which is substituted for another, often surreptitiously.  In this sense "through the ringer" could be correct.

Answer (score 7):

The underlying image is of clothes being dried out by being squeezed through a mangle (or wringer).  The correct form is thus "put through the wringer", with "ringer" only appearing when the the phrase **heard**, but the wrong word is written down.  RINGER and WRINGER are homophones (they sound exactly alike) but mean different things.

Comment: Actually, I'm sure there's some group of people somewhere who pronounce the words differently.

Comment: @Hot Licks  While they might be pronounced differently in different areas or in different dialects, I suspect they'd remain as homophones.  The "w" in "wringer" simply isn't pronounced in Standard English.  It derives from  Old English _wringan_, to squeeze.  The spelling of "wringer" retained the "w", even when it was no longer pronounced.  Cf wrong, wrung/rung (quite different words), etc.

Comment: Further ... "ring" ( as in "ring a bell") derives from Old English _hringan_, to ring.  There, the "h" sound had dropped out before spelling (sort of) stabilized, so it's not present in the current spelling of the word.

Comment: The correct procedure here is to close-vote, not endorse with an 'answer'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Um ...  I think Hot Licks raised a plausible possibility, even if it is (in my view) wrong.  "close-vote" (I'll have to look that up) would, presumably, simply abolish the original observation.  Or am I wrong in this?  Still learning the site conventions ...

Comment: Hot Licks is only pointing out that the two words need not be totally homophonous. The question should be close-voted as it (2) does not offer evidence to support that OP has checked that both forms are considered correct and (1) is based on an erroneous assumption. A website aimed at linguists should not be  offering 'RINGER and WRINGER are homophones (they sound exactly alike) but mean different things.'

Comment: Note that I was being somewhat (but not entirely) facetious.  It's probably impossible to find a single English word that is (even after allowing for accents) pronounced exactly the same by every "native" English speaker in the world.  And it's definitely not unusual to find groups which pronounce "silent" letters in certain words.